# React open a popup of specific object when clicking on the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

> I have images for every **Project** when i click on a image i want to open a modal for that specific object and display some info. But when i click on it now it opens a modal for every **project** i want it to only display a modal for the specific image i clicked on. ( on the image the red X button is the content that the modal renders and "Volvo Blog" is the projectName when selecting the image to the right.) when i click on the image to the right i want it to only display "Volvo Blog" under that image instead of all images  [image]

```
 class ProjectsSection extends Component {
state = {
 Projects: [],
 openModal: false,
 selectedModal: null,
};

async componentDidMount() {
 const { data } = await getProjects();
 this.setState({ Projects: data });
 console.log(this.state.Projects);
}
openModal = project => {
  this.setState({ openModal: true, selectedModal: project });
 };
closeModal = project => {
 this.setState({ openModal: false });
 };
  render() {
   return (
   <div className="Section">
     <h1>Welcome to my Projects </h1>

     <ul className="Projects">
       {this.state.Projects.map(project => (
        <li key={project._id} className="ProjectsShowcase">
          {" "}
```

> when this image is clicked the modal opens.

```
            <img
            className="ProjectImage"
            src={project.image}
            alt=" of Project"
            onClick={() => {
              this.openModal(project);
              console.log(project._id);
            }}
          />
```

> here i conditionally render the modal. **EDIT**: passed the values of the
> selected object as props

```
          {this.state.openModal ? (
            <ProjectModal closeModal={this.closeModal}

            projectName={this.state.selectedProject.projectName}
            projectImage={this.state.selectedProject.image}
            projectDescription={this.state.selectedProject.description}
            />
          ) : null}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be on the right path. You're calling `openModal` with the clicked project (`this.openModal(project)`), and you're updating the `selectedProjects` state with that project. What you're _not_ doing is using that project state in your modal. For some reason you're passing in `[this.state.projects]` when you should probably be adding `this.state.selectedProjects` - and I would actually call that state `selectedProject` because it will only hold one project at any one time. See if that helps.

Comment: i send the `selectedProject` properties as props now, but the main issue is still there. It render the same modal for every object in the array, i want it to only render **1** modal for the selected object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could make life a bit simpler for yourself by reducing the amount of state. The final piece of the puzzle then is just what logical check you need to make to determine if the modal is there. Below is what I think you could use, with some explanation in the comments.

```js
class ProjectsSection extends Component {
  state = {
    Projects: [],
    // openModal: false, - don't need, can tell just by if we have an id or not
    selectedModalId: null // use null to represent no selection
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await getProjects();
    this.setState({ Projects: data });
  }
  openModal = (project) => {
    this.setState({ selectedModalId: project._id }); // just use an id
  };
  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ selectedModalId: null }); // just reset to initial state
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Section">
        <h1>Welcome to my Projects </h1>
        <ul className="Projects">
          {this.state.Projects.map((project) => {
            // doing it with a variable for ease of reading
            const shouldShowModal = project._id === this.state.selectedModalId;
            return (
              <li key={project._id} className="ProjectsShowcase">
                <img
                  className="ProjectImage"
                  src={project.image}
                  alt=" of Project"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.openModal(project);
                  }}
                />
                {shouldShowModal ? (
                  // here note change to use the mapped project, not what is in state as that's more likely
                  // to result in problems down the line
                  <ProjectModal
                    closeModal={this.closeModal}
                    projectName={project.projectName}
                    projectImage={project.image}
                    projectDescription={project.description}
                  />
                ) : null}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```